# php parse print_r output

Tags: php

When I print an object using `print_r`, is there any specific utility function in php to convert the output to an object?

There seems to be enough output to reconstruct the object, but I couldn't find the exact functions to accomplish this.

Comment: Not really for `print_r`, I once wrote a converter for SO questions here, however it does not contain enough information to do that properly: https://gist.github.com/hakre/1102761 - but it works pretty okay for standard cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no automatic method to change `print_r` value back to an object. You are also missing important information like what type is stored at a key (string or number or ..)

You could use `var_dump` to get more detailed output that can be changed back to an object. But still this does not mean there is an automatic function for it.

Last you could use `var_export` ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php ) to get valid PHP output you can use.

You could also use http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php to pass objects around.

Comment: Thanks. `var_export` gives a 'recursion too deep' error for me at the moment, print_r doesn't. I haven't tested var_dump yet, but what function would convert that output back to php?

Comment: var_dump would show a *recursion* error if it encounters one. But there is no automatic function. You could write one, but I guess it would require some `eval()` to create the objects which doesnt seem like a good idea.

Comment: Also what is the goal? If you can use print_r or var_dump you already have the objects? Why recreate them? Are you trying to send the objects to another site? If so you should check http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

Comment: Okay thanks, I would expect there would be a way to synchronise objects in php, but maybe I'm asking .. Ah that comment you just entered is what I'm looking for probably :-)